# Undefined method `cache_template_extensions=' for ActionView::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am Trying to Update an old Rails application(Rails Version 1.3.2) to Rails 2.2.2. and while running the server I got this error

```
undefined method `cache_template_extensions=' for ActionView::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

**MY Full Error Stack**

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:530:in `send': undefined method `cache_template_extensions=' for ActionView::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:530:in `initialize_framework_settings'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:529:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:529:in `initialize_framework_settings'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:526:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:526:in `initialize_framework_settings'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:154:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `run'
    from /home/pavan/eclipse_workspace/TCL MITHAPUR/config/environment.rb:15
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

**UPDATE:**
Removed The line `config.action_view.cache_template_extensions = false` from config/environments/development.rb and run the server,but the url is showing default Rails **'Welcome Aboard Page'**. Am I Missing Anything?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line (from config/environments/development.rb or config/environment.rb:15)

```
config.action_view.cache_template_extensions = false
```

Comment: Now the server is loaded on the localhost but http://0.0.0.0:3000 shows default Rails "Welcome aboard" page. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Delete public/index.html.erb

Comment: You can enter here... http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12390/welcome-johny-derp